# I am having a problem displaying a image in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I do not fully understand the concept of binding textures in OpenGL, I can't get this to render a jpg image for my project, any insight to what I may be doing wrong?

```cpp
// Shader sources
const GLchar* vertexShaderSource = R"glsl(
#version 150 core
in vec2 position;
in vec3 color;
in vec2 texcoord;
out vec3 Color;
out vec2 Texcoord;
void main()
{
    Color = color;
    Texcoord = texcoord;
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
}
)glsl";

const GLchar* fragmentShaderSource = R"glsl(
#version 150 core
in vec3 Color;
in vec2 Texcoord;
out vec4 outColor;
uniform sampler2D tex;
void main()
{
    outColor = texture(tex, Texcoord) * vec4(Color, 1.0);
}
)glsl";
```

```cpp
    //creating the window
    GLFWwindow *window= glfwCreateWindow(1200, 700, "NEX_Tests", NULL, NULL);

    if(nullptr== window){
        std::cout<<"ERROR HAS OCCURED WHILE LOADING THE WINDOW\n"<<"\n";
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    else{
         int screenWidth,screenHeight;
           glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &screenWidth, &screenHeight);

           glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

        glewExperimental=true;
        if(GLEW_OK==!glewInit()){
            std::cout<<"ERROR HAS OCCURED WHILE INITILIZING THE GLEW LIBRARY\n"<<"\n";
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        //set the viewing port
        glViewport(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);

        //creating the vetex array object;
        GLuint vao,vbo;
        glGenVertexArrays(1,&vao);
        glGenBuffers(1,&vbo);

        glBindVertexArray(vao);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vbo);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(vertices),vertices,GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        //creating the element buffer
        GLuint ebo;
        glGenBuffers(1,&ebo);
        GLuint elements[]={
            0,1,2,
            2,3,0
        };

        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,ebo);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(elements),elements,GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        std::cout<<vbo<<"\n";

        //   glVertexAttribPointer(0,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,(3* sizeof(GLfloat)),(GLvoid*)0);
        // glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        //glBindBuffer(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY,0);
        // glBindVertexArray(0);



        //creating and linking the shaders
        GLuint vertexShader= glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);

        glShaderSource(vertexShader,1,&vertexShaderSource,NULL );
        glCompileShader(vertexShader);
        GLint success;
        GLchar infoLog[512];

        glGetShaderiv(vertexShader,GL_COMPILE_STATUS,&success);
        if(!success){
            glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 512,NULL,infoLog);
            std::cout<<"ERROR HAS OCCURED WHILE COMPILING THE SHADERS\n"<<infoLog<<std::endl;
        }
        GLuint fragmentShader= glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(fragmentShader,1,&fragmentShaderSource,NULL);
        glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

        glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader,GL_COMPILE_STATUS,&success);
        if(!success){
            glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader,512,NULL,infoLog);
            std::cout<<"ERROR HAS OCCURED WHILE COMPILING THE SHADERS\n"<<infoLog<<std::endl;
        }
        GLuint shaderProgram= glCreateProgram();
        glAttachShader(shaderProgram,vertexShader);
        glAttachShader(shaderProgram,fragmentShader);
        glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
        glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

        glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram,GL_LINK_STATUS,&success);
        if(!success){
            glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram,512,NULL,infoLog);
            std::cout<<"ERROR HAS OCCURED WHILE LINKING THE SHADERS\n"<<infoLog<<std::endl;
        }
         //delete the shaders
        glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
        glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);

        //layout of the vertex shader
        GLint posAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram,"position");
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(posAttrib);
        glVertexAttribPointer(posAttrib,0,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,7* sizeof(GLfloat),0);

        GLint colAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram,"color");
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(colAttrib);
        glVertexAttribPointer(colAttrib,2,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,7* sizeof(GLfloat),((void*)(2*sizeof(GLfloat))));

        GLint TexAttrib= glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram,"texcoord");
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(TexAttrib);
        glVertexAttribPointer(TexAttrib,2,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,7*sizeof(GLfloat),((void*)(5*sizeof(GLfloat))));

        //loading the textures
        GLuint tex;
        glGenTextures(2, &tex);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
        std::cout<<tex<<"\n";
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0+ 1);

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);


        //loading the image
        int me=200,me2=300;
        int *width=&me,*height=&me2;

        unsigned char* Image= SOIL_load_image("IceKarl.png", width, height, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGB);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, *width, *height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, Image);

        SOIL_free_image_data(Image);


        if(!Image){

            std::cout<<"ERROR HAS OCCURED WHILE LOADING IN IMAGE\n";
        }

        //running loop
        while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)){
            glfwPollEvents();

            glClearColor(0.0f, 0.00f, 0.00f, 1.0f);
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

            //glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
            // glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,6,GL_UNSIGNED_INT,0);
            // glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0);
            glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        }
        glDeleteTextures(1,&tex);
        glDeleteProgram(shaderProgram);
        glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
        glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);

        glDeleteBuffers(1,&vbo);
        glDeleteBuffers(1,&ebo);
        glDeleteVertexArrays(1,&vao);
    }

    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2nd argument of [`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) is the tuple size of the attribute. In your case this is 2 vor the position *(x, y)*, 3 for the color *(r, g, b)* and 2 for the texture coordinates *(u, v)*:

```cpp
GLint posAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram,"position");
glEnableVertexAttribArray(posAttrib);
glVertexAttribPointer(posAttrib,  2,  GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,7* sizeof(GLfloat),0);

GLint colAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram,"color");
glEnableVertexAttribArray(colAttrib);
glVertexAttribPointer(colAttrib,  3,  GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,7* sizeof(GLfloat),((void*)(2*sizeof(GLfloat))));

GLint TexAttrib= glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram,"texcoord");
glEnableVertexAttribArray(TexAttrib);
glVertexAttribPointer(TexAttrib,  2,  GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,7*sizeof(GLfloat),((void*)(5*sizeof(GLfloat))));
```

When you draw the mesh, then the texture and the vertex array object has to be bound.

The texture unit has to be set ([`glActiveTexture`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glActiveTexture.xhtml)) before binding the texture ([`glBindTexture`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindTexture.xhtml)):

```cpp
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + 1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
```

You have to assign the texture unit index to the texture sampler uniform ([`glUniform`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glUniform.xhtml)):

```cpp
glUniform1i(tex_loc, 1);
```

Get the location index of the texture sampler uniform ([`glGetUniformLocation`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetUniformLocation.xhtml)):

```cpp
GLuint tex_loc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "tex");
```

Bind the objects before the draw call:

```cpp
int texture_unit = 1;
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + texture_unit);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
glUniform1i(tex_loc, texture_unit);

glBindVertexArray(vao);

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,6,GL_UNSIGNED_INT,0);
```

---

There is a further issue when you generate the texture names. Generate 1 texture name rather than 2:

<s>`glGenTextures(2, &tex);`</s>

```cpp
GLuint tex;
glGenTextures(1, &tex);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, really appreciate it.

Comment: I tried doing it but now I am getting only a black box, sorry to ask again.

Comment: @KrishPatel So you made a mistake. Of course I've tested the solution and it works fine for me. Do you ensure that `glActiveTexture` is done before `glBindTexture` (everywhere)?

Comment: Yes, I have and I am just getting a black rectangle on the screen

Comment: @KrishPatel This is my test example code: https://pastebin.com/qQgWChi0. It works fine for me.

Comment: AH I see I was still getting the tuple sizes wrong, and setting glUseProgram in the wrong place, thank you for helping me.